# UFW logs blocked request on open port, what am I missing?

Tags: logging, ufw

> Nov 29 15:17:15 hostname kernel: [397768.554884] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0
>   OUT= MAC=[mac] SRC=[ip] DST=[ip] LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=52
>   ID=17050 PROTO=TCP SPT=56152 DPT=80 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 ACK FIN
>   URGP=0

As I understand it, there was a request to port 80, which was blocked. Most of the messages have `DPT=80`.

Which is weird, since port 80 is open for business and serving websites like never before. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Notice that your packet has both the FIN and ACK bits set. This is the last packet that the remote host sends in the TCP tear down (end of connection) procedure.

What happens is, when your host has finished sending it sets the `FIN` and `ACK` flags on the last packet. The remote hosts sends a packet with `ACK` set followed by a packet with `FIN` and `ACK` set.

```
Local          remote
FIN ACK ---->
        <----  ACK
        <----  FIN ACK (?optional?)
ACK     ----->
```

In practice, the remotes `FIN` `ACK` is considered optional so the netfilter firewall will flush it's connection table when it sees the `ACK` so when the `FIN` `ACK` packet arrives it has no associated connection and is dropped.

Comment: Well, this really makes logging stuff from iptables/UFW pointless, thanks for the clarification.