# Allowed IP's are logged as blocked by UFW

Tags: firewall, ufw

The rule in UFW for `SR.CSR.CS.RC` IP is:

```
ufw allow from SR.CSR.CS.RC
```

As described in the rule, `SR.CSR.CS.RC` can access this server over any enabled port.

But, when `UFW` is up and running, some lines are appears in `UFW` log file about request from `SR.CSR.CS.RC` IP has been blocked.

```
[UFW BLOCK] IN=ens3 OUT= MAC=11:00:11:00:11:ff:00:11:11:bb:ee:00:00:00 SRC=SR.CSR.CS.RC DST=D.ST.DST.DST LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=xyxyxy DF PROTO=TCP SPT=SPTSP DPT=SPTDP WINDOW=501 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0
```

Why am I seeing those logs while `SR.CSR.CS.RC` IP has be full access?
Is it possible to `UFW` considers requests from `SR.CSR.CS.RC` IP are DOS attacks?

**Note:** `SR.CSR.CS.RC` is IP in disguise

Is this entry related with this: [UFW logs blocked request on open port, what am I missing?](https://serverfault.com/questions/336132/ufw-logs-blocked-request-on-open-port-what-am-i-missing)

Answer (score 1):

I was searching the net with the very similar problem on my hands, and here is what I found. Ufw has several rule files:

**before.rules** - rules that should be run before the ufw command line added rules

**user.rules** - these are rules we add with ufw command

**after.rules** - rules that should be run after the ufw command line added rules
(and same for IPv6)

In before.rules you can find these:

*# drop INVALID packets (logs these in loglevel medium and higher)
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP*

*# all other non-local packets are dropped
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP*

So I assume that those [UFW BLOCK] log entries are caused by either of those - after all they are the only rules with logging.